# Updating library used in phonegap plugin

Tags: java, android, cordova

I'm using the [BarcodeScanner plugin for phonegap](https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner), which uses the Google ZXing library for barcode scanning. I installed this phonegap by using the command `cordova plugin add https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner` in my project directory.

I have edited some code in the ZXing library so that the app uses the front facing camera rather than the rear camera. I need to find a way to update the ZXing library so that my changes would work. Essentially I need a new `com.google.zxing.client.android.captureactivity.jar`. How exactly do I do that?

Thank you very much in advance.